# Se puede concatenar la sentencia UPDATE en vb.net

Tags: vb.net

tengo el siguiente codigo es para actualizar una base de datos

```
Actualizar = "UPDATE" + TABLE + "Set Estatus = '" & TextBox3.Text & "' WHERE Num_Orden = '" & Form1.Text_Orden.Text & "'"
```

quisiera saber como concatenar la sentencia "update" con la variable TABLE
,TABLE es una variable de tipo string que toma el valor de un combobox desplegable con multiples opciones

Ya que cuando pongo

```
Actualizar = "UPDATE MIBASE Set Estatus = '" & TextBox3.Text & "' WHERE Num_Orden = '" & Form1.Text_Orden.Text & "'"
```

Si se actualiza el registro.
Espero me puedan ayudar.
Saludos.

Comment: En tu caso te falla probablemente porque no pones un espacio despues de `UPDATE` y antes de `Set`, con lo que tu cadena queda algo asi como `UPDATETABLASet`. De todas maneras, es una malísima idea concatenar tanto el nombre de la tabla, como sobre todo los parámetros, te expones a varios problemas, el mas grave la [Inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La que buscas es:

```
Actualizar = "UPDATE " & TABLE & " Set Estatus = '" & TextBox3.Text & "' WHERE Num_Orden = '" & Form1.Text_Orden.Text & "'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Para concatenar la variable al Sting de la consulta es con &

Un ejemplo :

```
Dim ssql as String

    Ssql=string.empty
    Ssql= "Update " & Variable 
    Ssql &= " Set Columna= Valor"
    Ssql &= " Where 1=1"
```

Y ya solo ejecutas la cadena Ssql.

Comment: No me va la sentencia, me marca instruccion sql no valida. Dice que espera un insert o UPDATE, etc. pero no me actualiza.

Comment: Podrías subir tu código, exactamente como lo estas ejecutando. Así te puedo ayudar de mejor manera.